# Sveltekit error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, self-signed-certificate

I have a strange thing going on. I'm using sveltekit for the first time and in my project I was going to call an api to fetch data and got error: **request to ' ' failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain.** And this was in the sveltekit loading function. When I did the same thing in onMount in a component it works like a charm.

So I decided to start a new project from scratch using the sveltekit demo template. And without changing anything going to the todo page and getting the same thing:

> request to
> https://api.svelte.dev/todos/98e351d
> failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
> FetchError: request to
> https://api.svelte.dev/todos/98e351d
> failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
> at ClientRequest. (file:///C:/Users/myuser/Desktop/my-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/install-fetch.js:6246:11)
> at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:390:28)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
> at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
> at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

And shouldn't the demo template work without any certificate? So decided to start a demo template on another computer. And there the todo page works as it should. Without any error.  I have looked around for someone with a similar problem and there is a lot of people getting self signed certificate error but not related to sveltekit or similar to my problem.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Are you on a work/school computer that has a VPN or proxy? If so, try disable the VPN/proxy and see if you get the same errors.

Answer (score 4):

Because SvelteKit uses [SSR](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/appendix#ssr), when you fetch a URL from outside `onMount`, SvelteKit processes it on the server side (i.e. through node.js). But when you fetch a URL from `onMount` it is processed on the client side (i.e. through browser).

I think your self-signed certificate is installed in browser but doesn't installed in node.js. This is the reason why the error is occurred when you fetch the URL from outside `onMount` and not occurred when you fetch it from inside `onMount`.